# Как зарегистрировать сайт в поисковиках на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, seo

Не могу пройти этап подтверждения владения сайтом.

Добавлял мета-тег в файл layout app.blade.php туда, где формируется *head* каркас страницы, но ни Google консоль, ни Яндекс не видят.

Добавлял и файл html для подтверждения  в каталог *public*, тоже не определяет.

И есть ли какие стать по SEO на Laravel.

Comment: Поисковикам без разницы на каком фреймворке выполнен бэкенд вашего сайта.

Comment: я понимаю что нет разницы но куда вставлять файл с гугл консоли чтобы его определял ?в какую директорию можете сказать?

Comment: В корневую директорию, там где у вас `.htaccess`, `favicon`, `robots.txt`. По умолчанию это `public`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов в ларавеле роутер определяет адреса. Видимо надо создать роут с именем файла проверки. Или в (апаче, нгинксе) создать правило, исключающее имя файла проверки из отправки на index.php

Answer (score 1):

1 вариант: проверьте доступность созданного файла с помощью браузера.

2 вариант: попробуйте использовать для верификации сайта meta-теги. Прописанный Вами meta-тег должен появиться в исходном коде страниц при просмотре в браузере с помощью панели разработчика.

3 Попробуйте внести тестовые изменения в *layout/app.blade.php* - убедитесь в том, что правите необходимый шаблон на необходимом сайте, чтобы исключить человеческий фактор: когда открыт веб-мастер для одного сайта, а верификация проводится для другого.

Как вариант очистите кэш:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать другой способ подтверждения. 
Из всех доступных https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=ru наиболее простой - подтверждение с помощью отдельного html-файла, который нужно разместить в корне сайта (чтобы не путаться с фреймворками разместите файл там, где лежит robots.txt).